# Understanding C++ enum through UIInterfaceOrientationMask for Objective-C / iOS

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, enums, bit-shift

```
UIInterfaceOrientationMask is defined as:

typedef enum {
   UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait = (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait),
   UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft = (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft),
   UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight = (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight),
   UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown = (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown),
   UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape =
   (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight),
   UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll =
   (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft |
   UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown),
   UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown =
   (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft |
   UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight),
} UIInterfaceOrientationMask;
```

for an easy work lets simplify the enum:

```
typedef enum {
   UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait = (1 << 0),
   UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft = (1 << 1),
   UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight = (1 << 2),
   UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown = (1 << 3)
} UIInterfaceOrientationMask;
```

that means:

```
typedef enum {
   UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait = 0001,
   UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft = 0010,
   UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight = 0100,
   UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown = 1000
} UIInterfaceOrientationMask;
```

That is possible because this enum is using a C    bit shift:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts

then when we write:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}
```

in fact we are returning: 0011

Why? Because the binary OR

0001 OR 0010 = 0011

```
0 OR 0 = 0
0 OR 1 = 1
1 OR 0 = 1
1 OR 1 = 1
```

So far, I understand.

But, how is the method checking which orientation is valid?

Because if we have a simple enumeration we are checking if is equals 0, 1, 2 or 3

```
typedef enum {
   simpleZero,
   simpleOne ,
   simpleTwo ,
   simpleThree 
} simple;

int whatever = someNumber

if (whatever == simpleZero)
{
}
else if  (whatever == simpleOne)
{
}
.......
```

But, how the code is dealing with UIInterfaceOrientationMask? With Binary ANDs?

```
if (returnFromSupportedInterfaceOrientations & UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait ==     UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait)
{
// Do something
// Here is TRUE  0011 AND 0001 = 0001
}


if (returnFromSupportedInterfaceOrientations & UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft)
{
// Do something
// Here is TRUE  0011 AND 0010 = 0010
}

if (returnFromSupportedInterfaceOrientations & UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft)
{
// Do something
// Here is FALSE  0011 AND 0100 = 0000
}
```

Is that the way?

Thanks

Comment: The last `if` statement of `returnFromSupportedInterfaceOrientations` should be `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> //...
>
> in fact we are returning: 0011
>
> Why?

Because a very smart apple engineer decided to assign his enums bit shifted values.  If you really want to know why, it's because enums are [bitfields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field), which are probably one of the quickest way of testing for or applying any kind of "options" to a method.

> But, how is the method checking which orientation is valid?
>
> Because if we have a simple enumeration we are checking if is equals
>   0, 1, 2 or 3
>   ...
>
> But, how the code is dealing with UIInterfaceOrientationMask? With Binary ANDs?

If you need to test whether or not the rightmost bit is set in the binary number `0011`, you test `(3 & 1)`, which is true (because it's basically `(1 & 1)`).  Thus, because enums are just named integers (as you probably already know), you test the complete OR'd together mask against any one or more particular values you're interested in by ANDing to check whether the relevant bits are present in the mask.

In that specific example, it goes a step further.  By testing for not just the presence of the bit in the options mask, but the entire option, you get a "safer" test because it guarantees that *all* the bits of the option are there.  For more complicated bit masks, this makes more sense, but for simple ones like `UIInterfaceOrientationMask`, simple ANDing works.

Answer (score 1):

Your suggestion is absolutely valid: use "Bitwise AND" operator, then check the result for zero (target bit is not set).

As a machinery behind, you can imagine enums like a stash of color pensils. They can be sequential "red-orange-yellow-green..." as rainbow, since then there is no restriction to provide exact colors like "orange-blue-violet".

So its up to you to choose the values assigned to each enum member (and if you don't provide one, compiler will assign next available value by his own will), decide do you need sequential or custom-order values etc.